# How to launch program at login

Tags: windows, uwp, desktop-bridge, msix

I have created a msix package with the desktop bridge tool provided by microsoft and I want after the installation to see the program to start every time the user log in (launch at startup)

I have modified the manifest file of the msix file and included an extension code as described in this post:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/02/23/supporting-launch-at-startup-in-a-desktop-app-converted-with-the-desktop-bridge/

```
 <Applications>
<Application Id="MyApp" Executable="MyApp.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
  <uap:VisualElements BackgroundColor="transparent" DisplayName="Safeplace" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Safeplace">
    <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" Square310x310Logo="Assets\Square310x310Logo.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\Square71x71Logo.png" />
  </uap:VisualElements>
  <Extensions>
    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.startupTask" Executable="myapp.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <desktop:StartupTask TaskId="Myapp" Enabled="true" DisplayName="My app" />
    </desktop:Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Application>
```

When the user login, I have this error message (translated from french) :
Windows can't find 'C:\Program Files\app_1.0.1.0__cghhgghh\myapp.exe'.Please check that you have entered the correct name then retry.

And indeed when you search in this folder the exe file is effictively not at this place. The correct path is C:\Program Files\app_1.0.1.0__cghhgghh\VFS\ProgramFilesX86\safeplace\

Comment: Is this a UWP app or a Windows Forms app? They are different and a UWP app will not produce a *.exe file.

Comment: Yes it's a UWP app with an exe file but windows can't find it...

Comment: @GuillaumePoulain What's this specific exe? Do you mean you just include this exe as a content file in your project and then add it to manifest? The doc you mentioned is just a winform app and a desktop bridge project. But you seems have a UWP app, a desktop exe and a desktop bridge project, am I right? If so, also please tell us how did you set the entry point for your desktop bridge project.

Comment: Also please check the following blog for UWP as startup task: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/08/01/configure-app-start-log/

Comment: ok now it works i have changed the path of the executable in the manifest file, now I have:    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.startupTask" Executable="VFS\ProgramFilesX86\safeplace\myapp.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <desktop:StartupTask TaskId="Myapp" Enabled="true" DisplayName="My app" />
    </desktop:Extension>

Comment: Thanks to us for your help!

Comment: @GuillaumePoulain Glad to know that, you can post the answer out it you've got the question resolved. In the comment it's actually not clear for other who read it. So in general, it looks like you haven't set your executable path in the right way, right?